# Getting 'Insufficient rights' and 'userhelper must be setuid root' error/warning while using consolehelper

Tags: linux, permissions, sudo, centos6

'/usr/bin/myapp' is a link to '/usr/bin/consolehelper'.

When non-root user try to run '/usr/bin/myapp' on command prompt, it shows  '**userhelper must be setuid root**'. But running with '**sudo** /usr/bin/myapp' it works fine.

While using with GUI, it shows '**Insufficient rights**' popup. I tried by changing permissions of related files '/etc/security/console.apps/myapp' and '/etc/pam.d/myapp'.

I am getting same popup while opening '**System->Administration->Users and Groups**'.

Comment: To be more specific, I am using CentOS 6.4

Comment: The second case is definitely one of something that **should be** restricted to only the superuser, and it would not be surprising if that is true for the first as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am trying to run this app as root user, and expect that consolehelper will prompt for password. The same things worked me before with many other distros, what changes required in case of CentOS6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution! The problem was absence of setuid bit for /usr/sbin/userhelper. I set this using following command:

```
chmod u+s /usr/sbin/userhelper
```

This changed the permissions from '**-rwx--x--x**' to '**-rws--x--x**'